# React navigation dynamic tabnavigator: cannot navigate to a specific tab

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested tabnavigator which is  created dynamically(data are fetched and stored in redux store) . However from my homescreen, i have a horizontal flatlist which represents a shortcuts to the tabs. 
ex: a click on the second item should bring me to the second tab( I have 1 to 5 tabs, that depends on the fetched user data )
The problem is that im always redirected to the first tab.

Here is the structure of my app and what i've tried to do

my app main navigator  is a tabnavigator :( if a user has already logged in, he is directly redirected to the main screen).

```
 welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen},
 login: {screen: LoginScreen}
 main: { screen: AppDrawerNavigator}
```

my main screen(AppDrawerNavigator) is a DrawerNavigator with the following structure:

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
   home: {
     screen: HomeNavigatorScreen, // HomeNavigatorScreen has the flatlist which  
                                  // links to the dynamictabs screen
   },
   dynamictabs: {
     screen: DynamictabsNavigator
   })
```

here is the code i'm using to navigate when a flat list item is clicked:

```
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName: 'dynamictabs',
          action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName:`Tab${this.props.index}`})
        }));
```

DynamicTabsNavigator.js

```
class TabNavigator extends React.Component {   

  render() {
    const  MarksTabs = StackNavigator({
      marksStack: {
        screen:  MarkTabs(this.props.marks), // MarkTabs is a function 
      }
    });

    return <MarksTabs />
  }
 }

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  marks: state.userInfo.marks,
})
export const  DynamicTabsNavigator =connect(mapStateToProps)(TabNavigator)
```

// markTabs function

```
const MarkTabs = (marks) => TabNavigator(generatetabs(marks),configurationObject)
```

// generateTabs Function loop through marks array and generate the tabs //dynamically

```
generatetabs = (marks) => {
  lat tabs ={};
  marks[0].Cursuses.forEach((item, index, array) => {
    tabs[`Tab${index}`] = {
      screen:props => <NotesScreen {...props} data={item.Materials}/>,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        title: item.Name,
      })
     }
  });
  return tabs
}
```

what i've tried to do is to assign a router in a  static way and is built dynamically at runtime. and add navigation props when returning  (i've linked react navigation to redux store as well.
In this case the navigation works correctly, if i click on the third item i'm redirected directly to the third stack. But this solution suppose that i will always have 5 tabs which is not always  the case)

here is the code for the modification i did:

```
class TabNavigator extends React.Component {   

  static router = StackRouter({
    marksStack0: {
      screen: TabNavigator({
        'Tab0': {
          screen: () => <NotesScreen/>
        },
        'Tab1':{
          screen: () => <NotesScreen/>
        },
        'Tab2':{
          screen: () => <NotesScreen/>
        },
        'Tab3':{
          screen: () => <NotesScreen/>
        },
        'Tab4': {
          screen: () => <NotesScreen/>
        }
      })
    }
  })

  render() {
    const  MarksTabs = StackNavigator({
      marksStack: {
        screen:  MarkTabs(this.props.marks), // MarkTabs is a function 
      }
    });

    return <MarksTabs navigation= {this.props.navigation} />
  }
 }

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  marks: state.userInfo.marks,
})
export const  DynamicTabsNavigator =connect(mapStateToProps)(TabNavigator)
```

The problem is that inside a static declaration we cannot access any instance property or redux state in order to conditionally render tabs according to how many item i have.
I've tried to import redux store: store.getState(), but it's returning undefined.

I hope that my description is clear.

Any help of how can i achieve that please?

Answer (score 0):

TabNavigator of `react-navigation` has a configuration option called `initialRouteName`. Tweak that routeName to dynamic ones and I assume you can directly go to second or third or any tab without going to the first tab first.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig